# Highcharts y ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, laravel, highcharts

Estoy intentando crear un gráfico con highcharts a partir de unos datos que obtengo con `ajax` mediante `json`.

Este es mi `.js`:

```
function graficoData (data) {
    $('#chart1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Equipos por estados'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Activo', 'Reserva', 'En Reparación', 'Baja']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Número de equipos'
            }
        },
        series: data,
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/grafico-estados/',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            graficoData(data);
        }
    });
});
```

El `data` que obtengo es:

```
[
    {"estado":"Activo", "total":2},
    {"estado":"Baja", "total":1},
    {"estado":"Reserva", "total":1}
]
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos

Da un vistazo al formato de [Series](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Ccolumn%3E.data) en ello notaras que el formato (digamos); en vez de **"estado"** usa **x** y en vez de **"total":2** usa **dato:[2]** (y claro asi respectivamente para cada uno; me parece que así de momento la gráfica se mostrara, ya la presentación es cuestión como en realidad debe mostrarse la labor.

Éxito.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
function graficoData (data) {
   $('#chart1').highcharts({
   chart: {
       type: 'column'
   },
   title: {
       text: 'Equipos por estados'
   },
   xAxis: {
       categories: [data[0].estado, data[1].estado, data[2].estado]
   },
   yAxis: {
       title: {
            text: 'Número de equipos'
       }
   },
   series: [{
        name: 'Total',
        data: [data[0].total, data[1].total, data[2].total],
    }, ]
  });
}
```

Pero ahora me encuentro otro problema. Tengo 4 columnas posibles para mostrar, pero hay veces que uno de los estados que suele ser 0.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrarlo siempre aunque sea 0?

Mi consulta SQL en mi Modelo es:

```
public static function Grafico(){
    return DB::table('equipos')
        ->select('estados.estado', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->join('estados','estados.id', '=', 'equipos.id_estado')
        ->groupBy('estados.estado')
        ->get();
    }
```